# Curve modifier doesn't wrap plane around bezier circle

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'd like to wrap a plane around a circle. My plane has the solidify modifier which gives it a little bit of depth.

Based on what I can find online the curve modifier should be able to warp my plane in such a way that it wraps around the cylinder. But when I do it in my blender I get strange results. Here's one example. In this example it just puts the origin of the plane on the circle and then as you move x it rotates around the circle. But I want it to wrap around the circle as though it were made of clay and I pressed it against the outside of the cylinder. Ultimately I'm trying to do this with an svg so I can cut a hole in the cylinder with the image that I want.

Anyways, here's what I'm looking at.

[image]

[Here's the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RC4pafX22HDdZ2vpkRCJKbc-bqF4yVwk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried another axis?

Comment: Yeah, with how I've got it set up that will either make the plane really tall, like a column, or it disappears for some reason.

Comment: Apply the scales with Ctrl+A. Put the curve and the plane to the same place (the origins). The most important: subdivide the plane, because the modifier only can bend between verts. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ts4Y1mbZ2LvhI80Nd0Edjn5qR0s8TQuX

Comment: The only way to connect two vertices is with  a straight edge. Have you subdivided your plane?

Comment: Thanks for the file! I followed your guyses instructions on my file and yes, subdividing worked. At first I tried the subdivision modifier but that deformed the plane so I subdivided in manually by adding edge loops. Was me doing that consistent with what you meant when you said to subdivide it?

Comment: Did you place the subdivision surface modifier above the curve modifier?

Comment: It gives slightly different and undesirable results either way. subdiv first I get a horizontal oval. subdiv second I get a vertical oval. In either case it doesn't keep the rectangle shape which is what I want. It seems like one of those things where people use the word subdivide synonymously with "add edge loops"

Comment: Yes and no. Set the Subsurf Modifier to "simple" not to "Catmull".

Comment: I see it now. Neat.